# Input System Joystick with two sticks

Tags: unity-game-engine

As I understand it:
The "**gamepad**" has two sticks - left and right.
The "**joystick**" has only one stick.

My remote has two sticks, but it connects as a joystick.(I can't do anything about it outside of unity)

The problem is that one stick is inactive, I can't assign("**listen**") it in the editor, I can't reassign(**InputActionRebindingExtensions.RebindingOperation**) it in the game.
And my remote works fine in other Unity games, but I don't know what Input System they use.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

New Input Manager - should work for most well-known gaming devices.

But in unique cases, like mine, you can offer the player to assign buttons himself.

To do this, you have 28 joystick input axes("[old](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html)" input system) - which will correspond to the buttons, sticks, and switches on your device.

1. Create 28 Axes (yes, everything is manual) as in the screenshot
   [image]
2. Create a script that will allow the player to assign a button.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine;

public class ButtonTest : MonoBehaviour {
    public TMP_Text text;
    public TMP_Text text2;

    void Update() {
        text.text = "";
        //print the values of all axes
        for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++) {
            var axis = $"Axis{i}";
            text.text += axis + ": " + Input.GetAxis(axis) 
            + " | " + Math.Round(Input.GetAxis(axis), 2) + "\n";
        }

        //starts listening for any axis usage after pressing the space bar.
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) {
            text2.text = "Wait for key";
            StartCoroutine(WaitForAxisInput(axis => {
                text2.text = axis;
            }));
        }
    }

    IEnumerator WaitForAxisInput(Action<string> OnInput) {
        float[] axisSnapshot = new float[28];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 28; i++) {
            var axis = $"Axis{i}";
            axisSnapshot[i - 1] = Input.GetAxis(axis);
        }
        while (true) {
            yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
            for (int i = 0; i < axisSnapshot.Length; i++) {
                var axis = $"Axis{i + 1}";
                if (Mathf.Abs(Input.GetAxis(axis) - axisSnapshot[i]) > 0.8f) {
                    OnInput(axis);
                    yield break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]